# Ubuntu 16.04 does not shutdown properly from GUI

Tags: unity, 16.04, shutdown

If I try to shutdown Ubuntu from GUI (gear icon in top right > Shutdown > Shutdown) nothing happens.

The running applications stay open, the Desktop does not disappear, nothing.
I can continue working, open new applications, and so on.

If I shut it down with

```
systemctl poweroff
```

instead (no `sudo` required!), everything switches off the way I expect it to (it closes the open applications, Plymouth comes up, ecc).

In order to investigate the problem, what command does the GUI button provide?
Maybe if I run it from terminal it will help me understand the problem better, and maybe then report a bug if reproducible.